# Get Part of Date as separate variables

Tags: javascript

I am tasked with building a front-end for data in a JSON database. When working with the date, the information is stored in this format:

> 12/31/16

I need to use each of these values separatly. Is there a way to get variables like so?:

```
var month = 12
var day = 31
var year = 16
```

Comment: dateString.split("/") [MDN String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/splitk)

Comment: javascript has a Date object : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: @Matt.C - does not seem to be needed here

Comment: agreed, possibly unecesary, but the source date has a short year and the variable year has a long year so an object might be safer depending on the potential ranges?

Comment: I apologize, the 4 digit `2016` was a typo. I was mentally turning 16 into 2016 while typing, I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your date is a string. You can split it by `/`, which will result in an array. There after use array indices to get the value

```js
var _date = "12/31/16",
  splitDate = _date.split("/"),
  month = splitDate[0],
  day = splitDate[1],
  year = splitDate[2];
console.log(month, day, year)
```

Comment: better still, use array destructing.

Comment: @VictoryOsikwemhe - Destructuring: `var [month,day,year] = "12/31/2016".split("/")`

Comment: You also missed the 2016 part

Answer (score 2):

If you want to validate your date raw value, and your code to  support different cultures, Use moment js.

https://momentjs.com

Your example:

```js
function dateChanged(rawDate) {
  var mydate = moment(rawDate, 'MM/DD/YY');
  $('#day').innerHTML = mydate.date();
  $('#month').innerHTML = mydate.month() + 1; // months are 0 based
  $('#year').innerHTML = mydate.year();
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var input = $('input');
  input.value = '12/31/16';
  dateChanged(input.value);
});
var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js">
</script>
<input onchange="dateChanged(this.value)" type="text" />
year <span id="year"></span>
month <span id="month"></span>
day <span id="day"></span>
```

It's a time & date js framework which allows parsing and formatting dates & times according to patterns & locales
It's the best I know of

Comment: I knew moment.js was not a good choice here: _Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release._.

Comment: @shmulikfriedman Thank you, locales and patterns did not even occur to me. While other questions answer my question more direct without a library, you have given me something very important to think about.

Comment: @mplungjan, 
1. after I explicitly provided the format, it's not deprecated anymore, (also, the date format provided is of the asker not mine)
2. RFC2822 or ISO are a good practice formats if you controls it, but what if the raw date is coming from a user input or let's say OCR recognition? there you have to confront the discouraged format and still be able to parse the date

Comment: @Auzy another thing to take in count is languages, if you want let's say to get present the month name, moment will know how to give it multilanguage-wise

Answer (score 0):

So we all (except Matt.C) missed that you might want to coerce the YY into YYYY - it is VERY poor practice to store a year as two digits.

Assuming all dates are from this century:

```
var dateString = "12/31/16";
var [month,day,year] = dateString.split("/"); // very new method
year = "20"+year; // if needed
```

the above needs to be parseInt'ed to become numbers

Older more compatible

```
var dateString = "12/31/16",
    parts = dateString.split("/"),
    month = +parts[0],
    day   = +parts[1], 
    year  = parseInt("20"+parts[2]); // remove "20"+ if not needed
```

Note in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/5yaysbLa/) how **moment.js** does not like the 2 digit year either

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep that in mind. Unfortunately, that is how the data is entered into the database. I simply have to work with it.

Comment: Or have them update the database to contain a timestamp instead as it should.

Comment: I'm merely a contracted front-end dev. But I will pass that along to those in charge. Thanks for the suggestion.